# Paginator in a view function Django

Tags: python, django, web, pagination

I'm trying to add the paginate option on my posts page from my blog website. I want to implement the paginator on my view function that renders the page and I found this exemple from Django's doc but it doesn't work. Any help ?

view function:

```
def blog(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_posted')
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 2)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)

    context = {
        'posts': posts,
        'page_obj': page_obj,
        'title': 'Blog',
        'banner_page_title': 'Blog',
        'page_location': 'Home / Blog'
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/blog.html', context)
```

html rendering

```
<nav class="blog-pagination justify-content-center d-flex">
  <ul class="pagination">
      {% if is_paginated %}
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
          <li class="page-item">
              <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">
                      <span class="ti-arrow-left"></span>
                  </span>
              </a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}

      {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
          <li class="page-item active">
              <a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a>
          </li>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
          <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">
                    <span class="ti-arrow-right"></span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

the url route

```
path('blog/', blog, name='blog'),
```

Comment: What doesn't work, what issues do you face?

Comment: It doesn't render the pagination on my page. I mean, it doesn't appear the number of pages and it renders all my posts on a single page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `{% if is_paginated %}` as it isn't returning any value and that is why you don't see any of the numbers (don't forget to remove the closer if `{% endif %}`)

You can access your paginated objects from the `page_obj`

```
{% for post in page_obj %}
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the HTML with the changes

```
{% for post in page_obj %}
    {{ post.text }}<br>
{% endfor %}


<nav class="blog-pagination justify-content-center d-flex">
    <ul class="pagination">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link" aria-label="Previous">
                <span aria-hidden="true">
                    <span class="ti-arrow-left"></span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}

    {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
        {% if page_obj.number == num %}
        <li class="page-item active">
            <a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a>
        </li>
        {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <li class="page-item">
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                <span aria-hidden="true">
                    <span class="ti-arrow-right"></span>
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    {% endif %}
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I've tried to remove that if statement and isn't working either, I didn't thought to iterate with a for and I tried now but it's still don't working.

Comment: Could you update your HTML template with the changes made? I have it working on my test project.

Comment: How exactly ? I mean didn’t the html file updates by his self when I save the changes and restart the server ? I’m really stuck because I can’t find any errors and this update how can I make it ?

Comment: I updated my answer with the HTML template code (with changes made). Try that and tell me if you can see the pagination.

Comment: Oh.. now I had understood what was the problem. I was render the post in a for like this {% for post in posts %}, I didn't understood from the first time what do you meant with that for loop, after that I undertood and I changed the for loop and now everything works perfect. Thank you !!